# OVS switch and Tap interface- Connecting two vm using tap interface-ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, openvswitch

I want to connect 2 VM together using tap interface on Ubuntu.
VM2 will connect to VM1 by a tap interface on VM1.
I will use OVS switch to forward traffic from VM1 to VM2.

Scenario:

Router from ISP provide IP subnet dhcp: 192.168.100.2-192.168.100.255

VM 1: has OVS switch, ryu controller with flow manager and 1 tap interface.(Ubuntu 20.04) and interface name ens33
VM 2: has IIS server running on host.(Windows 8)
I want traffic to pass through the OVS switch and then go to the backend of Vm2 webserver.
I will use ryu controller to redirect web traffic to the web backend of VM1.

Find below my setup on OVS VM 1:
At start vm had already 1 interface as default ens33 with IP 192.168.100.112.
Create a bridge br1 add to controller ryu localhost.
Create a tap interface and connect to br1.
Provide IP to tap interface 192.168.100.25

Add nat to allow traffic through ens33 for internet connection :
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE

VM2:
IP address : 192.168.100.115
Gateway:192.168.100.25 (Tap interface)
DNS:8.8.8.8

VM2 will get internet connection only if VM1 has connection.

Does anymore has a better solution, how to connect VM2 to VM1 ?
I will pass all traffic through VM1 in the ovs switch then forward to VM2?
VM1 will be a central switch for traffic and hence I cam use ryu controller in the future to redirect traffic.
My VM2 will have a web server port 80 in the future.

Thank you